# How do we extend the Jenkins workflow dsl?

Tags: jenkins-workflow

If I'm working on a plugin and want to switch from using a step like so:

```
step([$class: 'Gradle', 
           switches: "-PenableInstallerDistribution=true",
           tasks: 'build install',
           gradleName: '(Default)',
           useWrapper: true,
           makeExecutable: true,
           fromRootBuildScriptDir: true,
           useWorkspaceAsHome: true])
```

to a nice dsl element like so:

```
gradle switches: "-PenableInstallerDistribution=true",
       tasks: 'build install',
       gradleName: '(Default)',
       useWrapper: true,
       makeExecutable: true,
       fromRootBuildScriptDir: true,
       useWorkspaceAsHome: true
```

and perhaps most importantly, show up in the snippet generator, what do I do? I've looked through what docs I could find, but still can't locate any advice on extending the dsl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you are not really customizing the step configuration beyond omitting `step`, then this is probably a waste of time since a future revision of Workflow core is likely to include syntactic sugar for “metasteps” like `step`, `checkout`, and (now) `wrap`. (And any `SimpleBuildStep` already shows up in the *Snippet Generator* under `step`.)

That said, if you do need to create a first-class step, you would need to add a plugin dependency on `workflow-step-api`, and typically extend `AbstractStepImpl`, `AbstractStepDescriptorImpl`, and `AbstractStepExecutionImpl`.

If you are attempting to implement [JENKINS-27393](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27393) then I would say that a useful implementation needs to wait for the infrastructural [JENKINS-26055](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26055), as merely wrapping the existing `Gradle` builder will not allow the flow to survive a Jenkins restart (or slave disconnection) in the middle of this step.

Comment: I was very excited to learn that anything implementing SimpleBuildStep shows up under the "Step" snippet. That definitely makes the first-class step a very small improvement rather than a huge one. I'm not directly attempting to close the gradle bug. Really we're just trying to port our existing build to work with the workflows - which seem awesome - and if my changed worked well enough for us I was going to see about contributing back officially.

Comment: Yes, it seems like a step in the right direction, just beware that without either JENKINS-26055 or [JENKINS-25879](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25879) it will not be practical to run a serious Gradle build this way.

Comment: Ah yes, the output thing. We can live with that one for now because you can at least go to the individual running step, and most of the time the build is unattended anyway, so as long as it shows up eventually we're good. Durability is a larger issue, but pre-workflow there is no good ability to resume a build anyway, so we're no worse off.